VScode: remote debugging - missing breakpoints
In preamble, please note I'm a very new user in VScode.
In a current project i'm involved, the workflow is more of less the following one:

A main bash script is run to load modules and specific variables
The previous script loads a "main.py" python file: its role is to chain different external softs and python codes
The external softs ask as well python scripts on his own

The script is run in a remote server (under Linux os whereas i'm under Windows one), but now difficulty now on this topic.
I'm using the Python debugger "attach" and i'm facing the current difficulty

if the first break point is set in the "main.py" file, it's ok; i can add another ones in the same file tu use continue and so on
however if i add a breakpoint in another python file (python file (2) here after) using either vscode idle (red point) or even a "debugpy.breakpoint()", it is simply bypassed
if my first breakpoint is set to python file 2, the debugging stops BUT it is waiting for the debugger attach (i've no control to run it)

1rst breakpoint add:
    import debugpy
    debugpy.listen(5678)
    print("Waiting for debugger attach")
    debugpy.wait_for_client()
    debugpy.breakpoint()

i guess i should additional information, but which ones ? what am i missing
To summary the program workflow:
bash script   ------> main.py ----------> external soft1 ----> etc
                         |                       |
                         |                       |
                   external soft2          python file (2)

Thanks
Paul
######################################################################
UPDATE
######################################################################
I've made a basic example that should reproduce the issue (breakpoints are also missied) - note the main advantage here it prints some information's i missed in my real program.
The example is composed of 4 files:

2 bash files
2 python files

In practice, type "sh start.sh"

File 1: start.sh

#!/bin/bash
python test_breakpoint.py


File 2: run_python.sh

#!/bin/bash
python inside_file.py


File 3: test_breakpoint.py

import os, subprocess, debugpy

path = os.getcwd()
shfile = "run_python.sh"

# /// DEBUGGING
debugpy.listen(5678)
print("Waiting for Python debugger: attach")
debugpy.wait_for_client()
debugpy.breakpoint()
# /// DEBUGGING

command_line = f"sh {shfile}"
args = command_line.split()
run = subprocess.run(args)


File 4: inside_file.py

import debugpy
print("\n*** here is a breakpoint ***\n")
debugpy.breakpoint()



the launch.json file is:

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Attach",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "pythonArgs": [
                "-Xfrozen_modules=off"
            ],
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1"
            }
          }
    ]
}

Whatever I implement, the following warning appears and any breakpoint ouside the main python file (test_breakpoint.py here) is ignored ...
... what am i missing?
Thanks for your help

0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Waiting for Python debugger: attach
*** here is a breakpoint ***
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

